# Is there any easy way to edit clearcase database using dbedit command?

Tags: clearcase, raima

Is there any easy way to edit clearcase database using dbedit command ?

I just want to remove an event/operation so that sync packets has no information about that event.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  Theoretically it is possible but you would likely encounter referential integrity issues.

Are you referring to MultiSite sync packets?  If so, it is possible to remove the oplog so that it is not replayed at remote sites.  What operation do you want to remove?